# Why are some websites not loading only in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, internet

1. http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2295386 is not loading, so my weather app is not working. However it is loading from Windows 7 running on same PC and connected to same network (pppoe/dsl broadband connection). I have tried from Firefox, Chrome and Chromium in Ubuntu.

**It worked around a month ago. But now it is not loading.**

2. http://skydrive.com also does not work in Ubuntu.

This is what Chromium shows.[image: error]
wget result.[image: wget]

Comment: Are you sure it does not work only in Ubuntu? "http://weather.yahooapis.com/" was disable by Yahoo. Try to open Chromium, press Ctrl+Shift+J (to open the console) and open the page you have problems. You should get some errors in the console that could help you find what is wrong

Comment: @Salem This was the original website. http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2295386

Comment: SkyDrive is working pretty fine under Chromium, Google-Chrome and Firefox. As of the weather link you provide, I can see it is a weather forecast feed. Which is working pretty fine but under Chromium/Google-Chrome it will appear certainly messy as the RSS feed doesn't include the stylesheet link thus the information seems disordered. This situation won't happen on Firefox and other built-in RSS Feed readers. You may wish to try a different application in order to check if you get better results.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo Why does not they work for me? Any idea? Works fine in Windows 7. The weather app is also working in windows.

Comment: Could be a network configuration problem. Can you download those sites with `wget`?

Comment: Updated the post with `wget` result.